# Making a Snake game (following a tutorial): I get the error, object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, game-development

So the following code is to make the actual snake with cubes (This passage of code is also the only part with the term `self.pos` is evident):

```
class cube (object):
rows = 20
w = 500

def __init__(self, start, dirnx=1, dirny=0, colour=(255, 0, 0)):
    self.pos = start
    self.dirnx = 1
    self.dirny = 0
    self.colour = colour

def move(self, dirnx, dirny):
    self.dirnx = dirnx
    self.dirny = dirny
    self.pos = (self.pos[0] + self.dirnx, self.pos[1] + self.dirny)

def draw(self, surface, eyes=False):
    dis = self.w // self.rows
    i = self.pos[0]
    j = self.pos[1]

    pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.colour, (i * dis + 1, j * dis + 1, dis - 2, dis - 2))

    if eyes:
        centre = dis//2
        radius = 3
        circleMiddle = (i * dis + centre - radius, j * dis + 8)
        circleMiddle2 = (i * dis + dis - radius * 2, j * dis + 8)
        pygame.draw.circle(surface, (0, 0, 0), circleMiddle, radius)
        pygame.draw.circle(surface, (0, 0, 0,), circleMiddle2, radius)
```

When I run the whole programme (which consists of a lot more code), I get this error:

```
File "/Users/shreevathsagorur/PycharmProjects/FirstStepGameDevelopment/Snake.py", line 30, in draw
i = self.pos[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I would really appreciate the help, as I am very new to this stuff.
Thank you.

Comment: Evidently you're assigning `None` to `self.pos` somewhere. Post a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Where is the `cube` initialized? `start` must be `None`.

Comment: Never mind. I got it to work, there was one line that I missed, that had nothing to do with this error at all. Thanks a lot for your time though, I really appreciate it.